# PhpStorm shows warning as methods not defined

Tags: php

I have created a common Connection class and passed it in constructor to automatically create connection.

Things work perfectly but **PhpStorm** shows them undefined as may be it doesn't dynamically inspects code.

Is there any solution to resolve this? Or am I doing a wrong practice and should create connection in each class individually?

Here is my some of code:

**DbConnection class**

```
  public function dbConnect(){
       // stuff
       return $pdo;
   }
```

**UserClass**

```
private static $conn = FALSE;

   function __construct ($db) {
       self::$conn = $db->dbConnect();

       //ERROR: Referenced method is not found in subject class
   }

   function test(){
       $query = "SELECT * from traccar.users limit 2";
       $stmt = self::$conn->prepare($query);

       //ERROR: Prepare is not found i BOOLEAN

       $status = $stmt->execute();
   }
```

**index.php**

```
$db = new DbConnection();
$user_access = new UserAccess($db);
```

Comment: Without type-hinting phpstorm doesn't know that `$db` in the constructor is a `DbConnection`. So either use php type hints (`__construct (DbConnection $db) {`), or a phpdoc comment (`@param DbConnection $db `).

Comment: Could you please provide a link where I can read more about this?